# Need help creating BIG Mountain Flyover

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, animation

I'm kinda new to blender and I need some help. So I need to create a shot where the camera flies over the mountain range and then zooms in on a small mountain house

What would be the best FREE way to create big scale realistic mountains (I was messing around with the ANT landscape but I found it hard to get the forms of the mountains right and the quality wasn't that good)

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Hi. I appreciate that you have edited your question to be more specific like the close reason suggested, however, looking at the 3 questions you initially asked and this new edited one, they all seem to be opinion-based, which would be another reason to close them. There is no *best* way of doing something. There are ways that work and ways that don't work, but it would be up to you to decide which way is best. If possible, try to find a way to ask the question that doesn't require an opinion (just removing the word 'best' would probably do it). Thanks.